# mongoimport: error parsing command line options: cannot use both --file and a positional argument to set the input file

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I'm trying to upload a .json file to my db with mongoimport. i'm using this chain of commands (without the sensitive info):

```
mongoimport <host uri that starts with: mongodb+srv://...> --authenticationDatabase "admin" --authenticationMechanism= "SCRAM-SHA-1" --collection "..." --file "C:\Users\Jose Miguel\Documents\tinto programa\tinto-programas-3\database\DATA\JSON\2022\JUNIO\JUNIO 2022.json" --username "..." --password "...."
```

The complete error is the following:

error parsing command line options: error parsing positional arguments: cannot use both --file and a positional argument to set the input file

what could be wrong? i've already read the documentation and everything seems to be in its right place.

EDIT: as per @Joe suggestions, I have edited my command chain to look like this:

```
mongoimport <connection string, now without quotes> --authenticationMechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1" --authenticationDatabase=admin --collection=<collection_name> --file "C:\Users\Jose Miguel\Documents\tinto programa\tinto-programas-3\database\DATA\JSON\2022\JUNIO\JUNIO 2022.json" --username=<...> --password=<...>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A positional argument is one that is separated from the rest of the command by whitespace, and not introduced with a preceding option that starts with a dash.

Mongoimport can take at most 2 positional arguments: a connection string and a file

Check `<host uri that starts with: mongodb+srv://...>`, if there are any spaces or shell-reactive characters, escape and/or quote the string

Many of the options to mongoimport can use either `=` or space to separate the option from its argument, however `--authenticationMechanism= "SCRAM-SHA-1"` may be interpreted as an empty string for auth mechanism, with "SCRAM-SHA-1" as a positional argument.  Use either `--authenticationMechanism="SCRAM-SHA-1"` or `--authenticationMechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1"`

Comment: thank you. yes, with the host uri I use quotes since the documentation doesn't really explicitly say you gotta use either quotes or just the connection string as it is. sorry for deviating a little from the original question, but I have followed your recommendation to use either an equals sign immediatly followed by scram-sha-1 and the later, and none work. " unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AtlasError) bad auth : authentication failed". I even tried to use 0.0.0.0 as a way to bypass any kind of IP block and nothing. I have edited the question with the commands I'm using.

Comment: "bad auth : authentication failed" is a very specific error - the auth request reached the database server, was understood, but was rejected.  That would mean the error in this question is resolved, t is best to keep questions focused. Check all of your auth parameters against the database setup, and ask a new question if you need more help.

Comment: yes, you are right. i was writing the incorrect password. now it works! thank you!